# Error When running RSpec in Ruby App Created through IRB

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, irb

I'm working on an exercise that gets me started on [Test Driven Development Using RSpec](http://rspec.info/%20%22test%20driven%20development%20(TDD)%22%20using%20RSpec)

I've been following the instructions and I've created a file repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/InsomniaNoir/address-bloc), and performed `gem install rspec`. However, when I try to run commands to test RSpec is functioning it throws this massive error at me and I haven't been able to find out why. I'm somewhat used to using Ruby on Rails, but this is my first application outside the rails framework.

Here's the error:

`` /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/jrshafer/bloc/code/address-bloc/specs/entry_spaces.rb (LoadError)    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'  from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'  from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'   from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'  from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'     from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'   from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'  from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'    from /Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' ``

I'm usually pretty good at finding fixes for any kind of error during development but this one has me stuck. I'd appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "created in IRB"? How did you create it? Apart from that it's really hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the actual code. It seems though that you are doing a `require_relative` somewhere, that does not point to an existing file. Go through your code and double check those spots where you require files.

Answer (score 0):

So, after staring at it for a while and comparing it to an example I realized I missed a case sensitive `Entry` in the `RSpec.describe`. Noob mistake.